# HOW CAN I WRITE 2 COLOR İN THE 1 TEXTWIEW?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

Hi:) I am using android studio(XML FİLE) and I want to write 2 color in the 1 text for the checkbox . How can I do this? Can u help me? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suZkm.png)

Answer (score -1):

You can create SpannableString and set it as text of your widget programmatically:

```
 val highlightText = SpannableStringBuilder(allText)
 val span = ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED)
 highlightText.setSpan(span, 0, mySpanLength, 0)
```

In the example `red` span of length `mySpanLength` in the start of the `allText` created.

Comment: thanks but this  does not work :(